# Emulator of eclipse can't return image, but real mobile phone can return image

Tags: android

I have the following code to return image, but I don't add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml.
Emulator of eclipse can't return image, but real mobile phone can return image. Why? Thanks!

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                    null, orderBy);
```

Comment: Are there any images on the emulator?

Comment: No! I don't know why.

Comment: What I meant was maybe your device returns images because you have images on your device. However, the emulator doesn't return images because you don't have any images in the external storage of your emulator?